# Passing long values into MLlib's Rating() method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to build a recommender system using Spark's MLlib library. (using Scala)
In order to be able to use the ALS train method , I need to build a rating matrix using the Rating() method (which is a part the package org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating). The method requires an int be passed as the user id . However the dataset i am working with has 11 digit id's and hence throws an error when I try to pass it.

Does anyone know if there is some way around this where I can pass a long value into the Rating method ? Or someway to override this method ? Or someway to uniquely convert the 11 digit number to 10 or 9 digits while keeping it an int?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend, I think, on the range of your ids. Can you simply take the Id modulo Int.MaxValue? That is:

```
(id % Int.MaxValue).toInt
```

or can you just hash it to an Int?

```
id.hashCode
```

Comment: The former seems like a fairly reasonable thing to do. However I wasn't sure about the range of my values. I was sure though that only a few million needed to be considered at one time. So i just created my own sort of lookup table for them.